# TypeError: tokenize_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batched'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a Sentiment Analysis on tweets using BERT and HuggingFace transformer library. I am facing the following error and I am unsure how to solve it despite searching for possible solutions online.

```
TypeError: tokenize_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batched'
```

Here are the relevant parts of the codes:

```
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/CSV/test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df.head()

from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

# Convert Sentiment into an integers
def transform_labels(label):
    label = label['Sentiment']
    num = 0
    if label == 'Positive':
        num = 0
    elif label == 'Negative':
        num = 1
    elif label == 'Neutral':
        num = 2
    elif label == 'Extremely Positive':
        num = 3
    elif label == 'Extremely Negative':
        num = 4

    return {'labels': num}

# Tokenize the tweets
def tokenize_data(example):
    return tokenizer(example['OriginalTweet'], padding='max_length')

df = df.apply(tokenize_data, batched=True)

# drop unwanted columns
remove_columns = ['UserName', 'ScreenName', 'Location', 'TweetAt', 'OriginalTweet', 'Sentiment']

df = df.apply(transform_labels, remove_columns=remove_columns)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Where should the `batched` parameter be used? This should be clear in the description so that people can understand your problem and help you.

Comment: What is happening is that, the way `DataFrame.apply` is implemented, `batched=True` [is being passed as argument to the function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#:~:text=Additional%20keyword%20arguments%20to%20pass%20as%20keywords%20arguments%20to%20func.) `tokenize_data`.  However, according to the signature/ definition `tokenize_data`, it does not have any `batched` parameter, so the error is raised.